# UNIX syscall 'read' and 'write' in Windows

Tags: c, windows, unix

As below code representation, it seems strange that the 'read' syscall dose not work correctly with C language in windows.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("a.txt",O_RDONLY);
    char *buf = (char *)malloc(4);
    read(fd,buf,4);
    printf("the string is %s\n",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

very succinct c code,  and the content of a.txt is 'abcd'. But when I run this code in windows (env is MinGW, compiler is gcc). The output is

```
abcd?
```

what is the character "?" in this output string?

Can I use "read" or "write" unix syscall in windows?

thanks advance.

Comment: You failed to ensure your string is NUL terminated. BTW you also fail to check if `open` was successful.

Comment: 'the 'read' syscall dose not work correctly with C language in windows.' - just think about how unlikely that is, compared with the chance of bugs in your code...

Comment: FYI, on Windows, `open`, `read`, and "file descriptors" are implemented by the C runtime library; they are not system calls. The Windows API uses `CreateFile` to create a File object for a device or file-system file/directory and return a handle for it. `ReadFile` reads from a File object that's referenced by a handle. The actual system calls (i.e. that switch to ring-0 kernel mode via `SYSCALL`, `SYSENTER`, etc) are `NtCreateFile` and `NtReadFile`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue have nothing to do with platform or operating system. It's just about you missing the *string terminator*.

In C a `char` string is really called a ***null-terminated*** byte string. That *null-terminated* bit is important, because all functions treating a pointer to `char` as a string look for this terminator to know when the string ends.

That means a string of four characters actually needs space for *five*, with the last being the character null-terminator character `'\0'`.

By not having the terminator, string functions can and will go *out of bounds* looking for the terminator, leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So:

```
char buf[5];  // 4 + 1 for terminator
int size = _read(fd, buf, 4);  // Windows and the MSVC compiler doesn't really have read

// _read (as well as the POSIX read) returns -1 on error, and 0 on end-of-file
if (size > 0)
{
    buf[size] = '\0';  // Terminate string
    printf("the string is %s\n", buf);
}
```

Comment: Might also want to add that some numbers don't map to a printable character in the current font, and that the logic called by printf typically prints a replacement character when this happens.  That replacement character is generally a question mark in a diamond, or the simplified form, a question mark.

Comment: thanks @Some programmer dude. But why my code run smoothly in linux instead of the header file sys/types.h and sys/stat.h

Comment: @suoyong One of the possibilities of *undefined behavior* is seemingly running well.

Comment: @suoyong Or do you mean you can *build* without errors without those header files?

Comment: @Edwin Buck  thanks the supplement.  every byte map a ASCII code. isn't it Right?  So where the question mark come from???

Comment: @suoyong Not all [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) characters are printable. And since you don't know what is actually being printed, it could be something out of range for ASCII (which is only a *7* bit encoding), it could even be something more than a byte (like a multi-byte UTF-8 encoded character?)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you.